# Overloaded child class function cannot call parent of similar name

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, scope, name-lookup

I am assuming this is one of those "just not how it works" issues, but I fail to see why. Why do I need to qualify `B`'s call to `A`s `Start` with `A::`. If I change `B::Start()` to `B::DoSomethingElse()` I could call a parameter less `Start()` without `A::`. So what is happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
  public:
    void Start(){
        
    }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        void Start(int x){
            Start();     // cannot call this  
            A::Start();  // can call this  
        }
};
```

Comment: What's happening is that simply this is how C++ works. There are things you can do to adjust the symbol lookups in these cases, via the `using` statement. See your C++ textbook for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the C++ standard (draft, emphasis mine) `[basic.lookup.unqual]/1`:

> In all the cases listed in 6.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; **name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name**. If no declaration is found, the program is ill-formed.

So the `Start` name has already been found, within `class B`, so the lookup is halted. Overload resolution occurs only after name lookup is complete `[basic.lookup]/1`:

> ...Overload resolution (16.3)
> takes place after name lookup has succeeded....

So even though class `A` and `B` have different parameters, this doesn't come into play here, since the name lookup is already complete.

When you do `A::Start()`, you are then using qualified name lookup, where you are actually specifying the class where the function appears, so the name resolution will find that version.

Answer (score 2):

The unqualified name `Start` used in the class definition of `B`

```
class B : public A {
    public:
        void Start(int x){
            Start();     // cannot call this  
            A::Start();  // can call this  
        }
};
```

is searched at first in the scope of the class `B` and such a name is found because the class declares the function `Start`. That is the name `Start` declared in the derived class `B` hides the same name declared in the base class `A`. To access the name `Start` declared in the base class `A` you have to use the qualified name.